# Change the way magento2 is installed so its upgradeable

Tags: magento2, installation, workflow

There are many ways to install magento2, deploying from GIT, Downloading from magentocommerce or doing a composer installation.

What i find odd is that those 3 different ways of installing result in 3 different structures. One where the files are in app/code/magento and the other in vendor/magento/

Also one where you can use the upgrade and connect wizard in the backend, and the other where you can do a easy composer update.

What i did a while back since composer kept failing on my dev location, is a git deploy which went smooth but now gives me a hard time updating. Having some dependencies installed from composer, but still stuck on 2.0.0.

Whats the best way to proceed, and whats normally the best-practice way to install, i'd say composer, but not sure what the community thinks. You guys think a fresh install, migration of extensions and theme + adding my DB is the right way to proceed? For now its not running that smooth.

For example what i did now is i made a fresh install via composer, looks the most clean to be honest. Connected it to my existing 2.0.0 db and did

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

but then the next errors pop-up

```
a:4:{i:0;s:1755:"Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_Theme schema: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Theme data: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Customer schema: current version - 2.0.7, required version - 2.0.6
Magento_Customer data: current version - 2.0.7, required version - 2.0.6
Magento_Cms schema: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Cms data: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
....
```

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Just-Ask-Alan/bd-p/ask-the-architect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it as installing Magento as different roles.

- We talk about [contributing developers](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/dev_install.html) as anyone who wants to contribute to the CE codebase.
- We talk about [integrators](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html) as anyone who understands Composer enough to be able to update the Magento software using the command-line if desired.
- We talk about [the easy installation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/zip_install.html) as the lowest common denominator; in that case, you download a compressed archive. You can do this if you have shared hosting with no access to a command shell.

Of those three, there are only two file system structures: one that has components under `app/code` (contributing developer) and one that has components under `vendor` (the other two).

In all respects, the Composer installation and the compressed archive installation are identical. You can upgrade either one using the [command line](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html) or the [Setup Wizard](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/upgrader/upgrade-checklist.html).

Upgrading Magento as a [contributing developer](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/dev_options.html) involves Git as well.

Comment: Perfect response. but nu the real deal, i think i made a huge mistake then trying to download it in a more flexible manner, i used the developer install (github contributing developers).. And thrown away the .git since i needed my own. Not that smart, i'd rather use composer... issue there is that my complete install has a custom theme, 3 extensions, 8 languages(and stores) and 500+ products (x 8 languages)... Is there a way easy to migrate. since its still on 2.0.0.. :( Thanks!

Comment: I don't really know how to do a manual migration (never tried it) but you're probably looking at doing a new Magento installation, moving files, doing `setup:upgrade` and `di:compile`, testing, and then copying more over. I hope someone has a better answer.